# Per-bundleid Facebook iOS url scheme

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I have encountered an unfortunate design issue with the Facebook iOS SDK. The problem is our company produces many branded apps from the same prototype codebase (think restaurant ordering) that all need to interact with the same Facebook app.

The problem is that if a user has multiple brands installed on their phone, the url schemes conflict and when authenticating from one app, the user may be returned to the wrong app!

I looked into Facebook's url scheme suffixes, but the documentation says multiple suffixes are searched *in order* (!), not relative to the corresponding bundle id. This is horrible. If it simply associated a suffix with a particular bundle id, our problem would go away, but as it is documented, it will place precedence on certain brands over other brands, which is no better than the default behavior.

Is there any way to associate a url scheme suffix with a *specific* bundle id?

Comment: No, why are they using the same app id?

Comment: Because we have about 80 brands and really don't want to create and manage 80 different Facebook apps when they are all using the same service.

Comment: I've read that it's possible to use a dialog for login/authentication instead of switching apps. Is this still possible under SDK v4?

Comment: Found it: `FBSDKLoginManager.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb`.

Comment: You are making the experience for the user way way worse

Comment: I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Use different app ids. If the apps have nothing to do with each other other than they are using the same backend. Because it is really confusing for a user to login to one and be logged in to the other app.

And it is way way worse to use the web login because that means that the user needs to type in their email and password. If you switch to the Facebook app they will automatically get logged in.

Comment: I agree it's way worse, but it's just not practical for us to maintain 80 app ids on Facebook, unless there is some way to automate it. It's enough of a pain point dealing with iTunes Connect.

Comment: There is not any way to automate it. But I would assume that you want users to login. Which will be way more likely if you use the app switch

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly specify the suffix for each app by setting FacebookUrlSchemeSuffix in the application's plist. When this happens, for the purposes of login and share dialog, the Facebook app will know the right suffix to use.

The only time it searches down the list of suffixes is for deep linking, which you may or may not use.

In any case, you might want to have different app IDs anyways as @WizKid recommends since you'll be able to get analytics for each app, and it also becomes easier to maintain.

Comment: So you're saying if I add this property to the plist, Facebook will be smart enough to know which url scheme to call back into when returning to the app, even if I have multiple apps installed? What is deep linking?

Comment: That is exactly what I'm saying. If you're not already doing deep linking, then don't worry about it.